# Root web app service disappears after deploying a virtual application to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app service in Azure, running on Windows. On the *Configuration* page, I have set up two virtual applications. The first is the default root application, and the second is a virtual application that I have manually added. They look like this:

[image: Azure app service]

The problem is that I need to deploy the virtual applications in this particular order:

1. `/api`
2. `/`

If I instead deploy `/api` last, then the root application disappears and becomes the default page:

[image: Default Azure page]

I deploy the virtual applications to Azure through two release pipelines in Azure DevOps using the *Azure App Service deploy* task:

[image: Azure App Service deploy task in Azure DevOps]

What should I change to be able to deploy `/api` while preserving the `/` application?

Answer (score 0):

By default, **azure app service deploy** task will always do clean deployment. It means, whenever azure app service deploy task executed, it will clean all the files in the site\wwwrooot and then deploy new artifacts. Due to this reason whenever you are deploying virtual application to app service, the root application is coming to the default stage.
To prevent this, add the below line to the **Additional arguments** in Azure app service deploy task, Virtual application deployment pipeline as below.

```
-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=wwwroot
```

[image]

Save the configuration and run the virtual application pipeline. Once completes verfiy the normal application URL.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. Although in the log it wrote:
`2023-05-02T05:52:52.8818854Z Info: Object dirPath (.\wwwroot) skipped due to skip directive 'CommandLineSkipDirective 2'.` and `2023-05-02T05:52:53.8789812Z Info: Object dirPath (myappservice/myvirtualapp\wwwroot) skipped due to skip directive 'CommandLineSkipDirective 2'.`. Is your app service Windows- och Linux-based? I wonder what else I can try.

Comment: @DanielJonsson, I tried in windows app service. have you verified wwwroot folder in kudu portal to confirm changes after deployment?

Comment: After I have deployed the virtual `api` application, in Kudu, the only file that appears in the `wwwroot` folder is `hostingstart.html`. So it's still deleting all files there, even though I added `-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=wwwroot` to the additional arguments in Azue DevOps.